# Click on 'Google' in Google Maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, cordova

In my angularjs mobile project I have implemented Google Maps, but in the app there is a "Google" tag at bottom left ogfmy map, and clicking on it will take me to the google map app and not able to return to my App,Please suggest a turnaround for this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prevent the default behaviour of the click on the link and open it on inAppBrowser instead.
First install inAppBrowser plugin and then add this code (map-canvas is the id of you map, it might be different, change it if necessary)

```
var googleMap = document.getElementById("map-canvas");
var anchors = googleMap.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i+=1)
{
    anchors[i].addEventListener("click", openInAppBrowser);
}

function openInAppBrowser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(this.href, "_blank", "location=yes");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to write that tapping the link opens it inside the webview of your application, replacing your own.

Find the link in the source make sure it will open in either InAppBrowser or using _blank so it'll open in the browser app instead.

Comment: how exactly should i do that in angularjs?